# Get only text from parent <td>

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

In web site it has footer like this

```
<td class=resutinfo >
    Displaying 1 - 10 of 41 records Results per page: 
    <select onchange="javascript:gotoRow(1);" name="pageSize>
        <option value=10, selected="true> 10 </option>
        <option value=20, > 20 </option>
        <option value=10, > 30 </option>
    </select>
</td>
```

**Issue:**

When I use `getText()` for this `<td>`, it displays value like this

> Displaying 1 - 10 of 41 records Results per page: 10 20 30

but I need only means i don't want, select-options.

> Displaying 1 - 10 of 41 records Results per page:

Could you please give advice how get that string only.

Answer (score 3):

The idea is you get text of `<td class="resutinfo">` first, which should be

> Displaying 1 - 10 of 41 records Results per page: 10 20 30

Then you get the text of the `<select>`, which should be

> 10 20 30

Then replace it with empty string to remove.

```java
String tdText = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//td[@class='resutinfo']")).getText();
String selectText = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//td[@class='resutinfo']/select")).getText();
tdText.replace(selectText, "").trim();
```

Answer (score -1):

or a pure xpath

```
.//td[@class='resutinfo']/child::text()
```

Comment: -1, this will result in an exception. Selenium expects physical DOM elements to be returned.